# Escaping a Windows server file path string with single and double backslashes in it?

Tags: php

I have a Windows server file path that I'm having a lot of difficulty escaping because of PHP's magic quotes feature. Assuming that turning this setting off isn't trivial, how would I go about escaping this path?

Example:

```
\\SERVER\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.dtsx
```

To complicate things further, this path would need to run as part of a command wrapped in another set of quotes since it ultimately runs via a command prompt utility (called in SQL). The full command would look something like this:

```
$package =
            'dtexec.exe /f "\\SERVER\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.dtsx" ' + 
            '/set \Package.Variables[User::Param1].Properties[Value];"' + CAST(@param1 AS varchar) + '" ' + 
            '/set \Package.Variables[User::Param2].Properties[Value];"' + CAST(@param2 AS varchar) + '" ' + 
            '/set \Package.Variables[User::Param3].Properties[Value];"' + CAST(@param3 AS varchar) + '"';
```

I think my main challenge is the server file path if anyone can lend a hand here, though! Thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: Fortunately php allows you to use a sane character as path delimiter as it is used outside the MS-Windows world: a simple forward slash (`/`). So you path is simply `//SERVER/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.dtsx` which simplifies escaping quite a lot :-)

Comment: I should've clarified- this is for a Windows server, so forward slashes would fail here :(

Comment: No! That is exactly what I tried to tell you: you can use forward slashes even when still working under a MS-Windows environment. PHP allows that as long as you use those paths inside php. This _may_ obviously not be the case if you try to use the paths _outside_ php.

Comment: I'm definitely curious of the use case there, but unfortunately the path built in PHP is used outside. It ultimately runs inside xp_cmdshell in SQL Server, which expects a Windows path so I think it would break here!

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something different. Give it a try, MS-Windows is pretty inconsistent in such things. You might be lucky, you might be back where you started ;-)